# Unable to copy SSH key from Win10 to Ubuntu server using PSCP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, scp, pscp

I'm trying to copy my .pub key to my server that is on the same router.
I keep getting a "No such file or directory" error and I just can't get why as the file is clearly there.

```
PS C:\Users\black> ls ~/.ssh/homeUbuntu

    Répertoire : C:\Users\black\.ssh\homeUbuntu

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       22/05/2020     20:35           3326 id_rsa
-a----       22/05/2020     20:35            737 id_rsa.pub

PS C:\Users\black\.ssh\homeUbuntu> pscp -P 19198 ~/.ssh/homeUbuntu/id_rsa.pub black@192.168.1.45:/home/black/.ssh/bws_key.pub
~/.ssh/homeUbuntu/id_rsa.pub: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it turns out you have to use C:/Users/black/.ssh/homeUbuntu/id_rsa.pub for it to work correctly on windows.